# Half of my laptop screen shows greenish colour

Tags: laptop, display

Half of my laptop screen is showing a greenish color.

When I switched on my laptop this morning, it appeared like the picture below.

[image: laptop screen with greenish screen]

I am sure that my laptop hasn't been dropped.

Comment: God wont help here. Does it change when you open/close the lid?

Comment: Nope.. it remains same

Comment: The wire connecting to the monitor might not be tight.

Comment: which wire.. the laptop display wires inside the system..?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The symptom suggests that the red signal is being lost because of an electrical problem.

Comment: ok, let me check that once.

Comment: If you have warranty, you can bring it in. Your screen is missing sufficient RGB data (incomplete set) for that part of the screen that is showing green. Possible reasons is as mentioned: bad wiring or bad connector.

Comment: let me check friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last chance to avoid repair:

Boot on a Linux LiveCD or USB key. If the display is fine, you have a driver or other software problem.

Try with an external monitor on the HDMI/DisplayPort/VGA port. If the display is also half green it's either software or a hardware issue on the mobo (which would be extremely weird).

Now, if the red signal was broken in the motherboard-to-LCD cable, the display would be completely green, not just partially. Thus the cable is fine. The motherboard is probably fine too.

Most likely one of the row driver chips in the LCD is busted, and you will need a replacement LCD, or a technician skilled enough to replace the LCD control board.